# Special characters appearing at the beginning of label text in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

This is the Designer file for my Windform applciation where I created my UI. At the top of the file, there's a Label control with the text 'Name12:'.
[image]

When I run my program, I encounter an issue where the ':' character (also others like '$') appears at the beginning of my string. Although the code behind displays the string as 'Name12:', the label control actually displays ':Name12' (also the character '<' is displayed as '>'). I've checked the properties, but I'm not sure if there's something I need to disable to fix this issue. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?
[image]
Edit: The property RightToLeft is set to 'No'

Comment: Look at the RightToLeft property of the controls you think look fishy. Presumably you changed that value.

Comment: @Ralf It's set to 'No' everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, when creating a child form, the Windows Forms sets the RightToLeft property to 'Yes' by default. To avoid this, set the RightToLeft property to 'No' when creating the child form.

```
Form childForm = new Form();
childForm.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
```